# android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout - double trouble

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I got 2 problems with the code below and google couldn't help me :/ 
1. The `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` 
just appear on eachother, they do not share the line like they are supposed to. If I erase the design and leave only the Edittexts it works fine.

2.The width size of `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` is set to 'match_parent' but it only shows a tiny line instead. Only changes when i set a numerical dp value.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/rgGender">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etDay"
        android:hint="Day"
        android:inputType="number"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etMonth"
        android:hint="Month"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are giving `layout_width="match_parent"` to both the sibling TextInputLayouts which are supposed to be adjusted Horizontally(`android:orientation="horizontal"`) and at time of space allocation the first child of the LinearLayout getting the whole width of parent so nothing left for the second one.

`MATCH_PARENT` means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any.

`WRAP_CONTENT` means that the view wants to be just large enough to fit its own internal content, taking its own padding into account.

So, either give `wrap_content` width to both siblings or if you want the complete width to be divided in both the siblings in any ratio then use weight attribute.

Comment: @Shay hey... I hope my answer is solving your problem and if so mark it done.